# fetch request, set-cookie and cookie are ignored ,after I set credentials: "include"

Tags: cors, fetch-api

1. I use fetch to post a cross origin request, the response is successful with set-cookie header:

```
    Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:true
    Access-Control-Allow-Headers:Content-Type
    Access-Control-Allow-Methods:*
    Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
    Access-Control-Max-Age:100
    Set-Cookie:CSESSIONID=594747de551d49dcb278bb6a9ad71ccb; Domain=jdcf88.com; Expires=Tue, 12-Sep-2017 08:40:30 GMT; Path=/
```

2. Then I fetch data by get request, but I find that the get request doesn't have cookie request header.the code is:

```
       fetch('https://xxx.jdcf88.com/login/isLogin?userId=4', {
            method: "get",
            credentials: "include",
            mode: "cors",
            body: body
        })
```

I am pretty sure that the cookie is set to the domain jdcf88.com.
3. I don't know why the fetch request don't have cookie header , the server has set Access-Control-Allow-Credentials to be true, the credentials is include.

Answer (score 4):

Your server responds with a Access-Control-Allow-Origin:* , which is incompatible with include credentials. Try explicitly setting your origin to the address of your client.

So your server should respond with 
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:8080 (or whatever your client address is)